# How can I load a class dynamically in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a project like below:

```
myProject
    myApp
        migrations
        templates
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        modules.py
            class_A
            class_B
            class_C
        urls.py
        views.py
```

I would try to load a class from modules.py dynamically in my views.py like below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request, claz):
    # claz would be one of class_A, class_B or class_C
    mod = __import__("modules."+claz)
    fun = mod()
```

But I always get errors like below:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp/class_A/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'modules'
```

Can anyone help me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: How about using `getattr()`, like `from . import modules; print(getattr(modules, claz))` ?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks your patience.
After trying, I got error like below :
```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp/class_A/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
type object 'm01' has no attribute 'class_A'
```

Comment: How about adding a period before "modules": `__import__(".modules."+claz)`

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks your patience.

As your suggestion, I still get an error after try :

No module named '.modules'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myApp/class_A/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value: No module named '.modules'